# How to define a vector of arbitary length

Tags: variable-definitions, vector

I need to use a vector of length which I can change, indexed symbolically

So for e.g. when N=3 I'd like to have

```
vec={c1,c2,c3}
```

when N=5

```
vec={c1,c2,c3,c4,c5}
```

etc. I can't think of any way of doing it using tables and so on? currently i'm jut typing it out, and when N=50 this is ugly.

Comment: agreed. sorry, I did look. thankyou

Comment: vec[[n]] does it for free. Are you sure that you need individual names?